# DevOps Azure CLI Task - Granting Admin Consent to App Registration throws error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-app-registration

I'm hoping that someone can shed some light on this because I'm a little bit stuck.

....

I have an Azure CLI task in a DevOps Release Pipeline.

This is running using a Service Principal which is a member of the **Application Administrators** group.

When I run the following command ...

```
az ad app permission admin-consent --id $(Variables.SharePointAppRegAppId)
```

I get an error message:

```
ERROR: Forbidden({"message":"Forbidden","httpStatusCode":"Forbidden","xMsServerRequestId":null,"clientData":{"errorCode":"MsaUserWithNoAccessToTenant","localizedErrorDetails":null,"operationResults":null,"timeStampUtc":"AAAAA","clientRequestId":"BBBBB","internalTransactionId":"CCCCC","tenantId":null,"userObjectId":"DDDDD","exceptionType":"Exception"},"stackTrace":null})
```

I initially thought that it might be permissions based - that maybe it doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform this task, but according to this Microsoft article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal#prerequisites)

> To grant tenant-wide admin consent, you need:
>
> - An Azure AD user account with **one of the following roles**:
>
>   - Global Administrator or Privileged Role Administrator, for granting consent
>     for apps requesting any permission, for any API.
>   - Cloud Application Administrator or **Application Administrator**, for granting consent for apps requesting any permission for any API, except Azure AD Graph or
>     Microsoft Graph app roles (application permissions).
>   - A custom
>     directory role that includes the permission to grant permissions to
>     applications, for the permissions required by the application.

Now - the error is otherwise saying "**MsaUserWithNoAccessToTenant**" but I'm already using this same Service Principal to actually create and deploy the entire environment using Pulumi - including creating and setting up new instances, and **creating** brand new AAD App registrations in the same tenant.

For reference - here is the YAML task definition

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Grant Admin Consent to AAD App Registration'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'appreg-infra'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az ad app permission admin-consent --id $(Variables.SharePointAppRegAppId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I added DevOps **service principal** and one **user** account named `Sri` to Application Administrator Group like below:

[image]

In my case, I tried to grant **admin consent** to SharePoint permissions of below application via DevOps Azure CLI Task:

[image]

When I ran DevOps Azure CLI Task to grant admin consent, I got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

When I tried to run same commands by logging as service principal via CLI locally, I got **same error** like below:

```
az login --service-principal -u <spID> -p <clientsecret> --tenant <tenantID> --allow-no-subscriptions
az ad app permission admin-consent --id <SharePointAppID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, granting **admin consent** requires **`Azure AD user account`** with one of the Administrator roles.

To **resolve** the issue, you need to sign in with **user account** having admin privileges instead of service principal.

Now, I signed in with Azure AD user account `Sri` which is a member of **Application Administrator** group by running below CLI commands and got response like this:

```
az login -u <username> -p <password> --tenant <tenantID> --allow-no-subscriptions
az ad app permission admin-consent --id <SharePointAppID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where **admin consent** is granted successfully in the application like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer to this. Indeed we found that this was a service principal thing.